Is two degree quantum entanglement possible? And by two degree of entanglement I mean one in space and other in time?
Whenever we try to entangle two particles, the entanglement lasts for a very short period. If we observe our present universe we can see that all the matters present in our universe are finely connected to each other by an invisible thread and on top of that thread different vibrations coupled with time and space gives rise to the variety we see all around ourselves .. like different beads on a thread in a necklace so maybe if we can achive this 2 degree of entanglement we can actually make quantum computers feasible

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your implied question is effectively: can more than 2 particles be entangled? The answer to that is yes. However, 3 or more particles cannot be maximally entangled due to “monogamy of entanglement”.
Further, while there is no particular upper limit on the number of particles that can be somewhat entangled, in practice there is a limit. That is due to what is called decoherence. So no, everything is not connected to everything else via entanglement.
